# Php keeps saying error while deleting a person

Tags: sql, mysql

Trying to delete a person 'Sarah Smith' from table named 'Medals'

```
DELETE FROM Medals
JOIN Athletes ON Medals.AthleteID = Athletes.AthleteID
WHERE AthleteName = 'Sarah Smith'
```

SQL phpmyadmin always says syntax error in last line

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'JOIN Athletes ON Medals.AthleteID = Athletes.AthleteID
>
> WHERE AthleteName = 'S' at line 3

Comment: As you get an error message, please share it as text

Comment: edited: just added in the first line

Comment: Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: `DELETE FROM Medals WHERE AthleteID IN (SELECT AthleteID FROM Athletes WHERE AthleteName = 'Sarah Smith')`

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the table name before `FROM`

```
DELETE Medals FROM Medals
JOIN Athletes ON Medals.AthleteID = Athletes.AthleteID
WHERE AthleteName = 'Sarah Smith'
```

See the [syntax documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) for more information